# Malloc with int **

Tags: c, pointers, int, malloc

if I have as an argument int **a in my function
I was wondering what is the difference between `a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(a)*(length)` and `*a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(a)*(length)`
I've discovered malloc last week so I don't understand everything yet.
Thank you !

Comment: With `int **a`, ask  "what is the difference between `a` and `*a`?"

Comment: Note that `sizeof(a)` is unlikely to be what you want in either case.  What you want instead depends on which variant you choose.

Comment: If you just now are learning this, you might want to get it right from the start: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays). Otherwise some poor soul has to spend time deprogramming you, when you become a professional programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc` just returns a `void *` pointer, nothing more.

`a` is a pointer to pointer.

The right side of the Equals Sign is not important here, so leave the right side alone. Now we got:

```
// 1st code fragment
int **a1;
// Asign a null pointer to a1, now a1 is a NULL pointer
a1 = (int **)NULL;

// 2rd code fragment
int **a2;
// Asign a null pointer to the pointer pointed by a2.
// Here may crash actually, because a2 is not initialized yet.
*a2 = (int *)NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first case takes the address of the memory allocated by the call to `malloc`, and assigns it to your variable `a`.
The second takes the address of the memory allocated by `malloc` and stores that in whatever memory `a` happens to be pointing at.

There's another question here, though, which is specifying how much memory you should allocate. If you want `a` to store an array of pointers to integers, I would use expression `a = (int**) malloc( length * sizeof(*a) );` which makes it clear that you are allocating space for a number of integer pointers.

On the other hand, if you want to allocate space for a number of integers (not pointers) and you are sure that `a` is pointing at a variable of type `int*`, then use the expression `*a = (int*) malloc( length * sizeof *(*a) );`

Finally, note that (per chux's link below) it is unnecessary and not recommended to cast the result of `malloc()`. I have left in the casts here only for clarity, because they illustrate that we're storing the returned value in a different type of variable in each case.

Comment: If code uses `a = malloc(sizeof *a * length);` then, coding the type is not needed as in `a = (int**) malloc( length * sizeof(int*) );`.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: Good point, chux, but I'm still not sure whether the user wanted to allocate integers or pointers

Comment: In the 2nd case, code can use `*a = malloc(sizeof *(*a) * length);` instead of `*a = (int*) malloc( length * sizeof(int) );`.  Again, the type does not need to be coded here.

Comment: You may enjoy [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @TimRandall thanks for the editing, though it collided with mine.

Answer (score 1):

> int **a;

`a` is of type integer double pointer.

> a = (int **) malloc(sizeof(a)*(length));

uninitialized memory of size `sizeof(a)*(length)` allocated to `a` upon malloc success.

> *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(a)*(length);

uninitialized memory of size `sizeof(a)*(length)` allocated to `a[0]` (if a initialized only other wise it crashes) upon malloc success.

Note: sizeof(a) is sizeof double pointer, it is 4 bytes for 32 bit mechine. So allocating 
same memory i.e `sizeof(a)*(length)` memory in both cases may not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will answer your question, but I am not 100% sure. Let's find out!

You mention 'my function', which makes me think that you are not referring to your main function, but that you are writing a function (perhaps to allocate a). If that is the case, the difference is the following; a simple variable `int a` in the argument list of a function will be passed by **value**. That means that if you call the function, say `void foo(int x)`, with a certain value, that value will be copied to the function. Therefore, when you enter the function, you are not working with the **actual variable**; instead, you are working with a copy. Where a particular variable exists and where it does not, is referred to as a variable's **scope**.

Now to your practical case: I presume you want to allocate an array in a function. If you use your first example:
`a = (int **)malloc(sizeof(a)*(length)` in a function where `a` is an argument, the same thing will happen as I outlined above. I.e., `a` gets copied to the function and then you allocate it there. However, when your function ends, `a` is destroyed (note: the pointer that is, the memory is not freed correctly)! If my assumption is correct, this will probably not be the desired result.

By contract, if your function has `int *a` as an argument, the argument will be passed by  address. Now, any changes you make (by dereferencing `a` using the `*` operator), will persist even when you return to the place where your function was called.

Comment: there is no `std::` in `C`

Comment: C++ examples are not particularly welcome in questions tagged [c], your assertion of relevance notwithstanding.  Beyond that, although scope may indeed be relevant to the OP's situation, it is not directly relevant to the actual question.

Comment: Good points, I'll remove the example and leave the last two paragraphs.